# "theme" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: jsf

I want to use this code into JSF page:

```
<div style="height:964px; background-color: #FFFFFF; overflow:hidden; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #56667F; border-radius: 4px; text-align: right; line-height:14px; font-size: 12px; box-sizing:content-box; font-feature-settings: normal; text-size-adjust: 100%; box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 0 0 #56667F; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 99%;"><div style="height:944px;"><iframe src="https://widget.coinlib.io/widget?type=full_v2&theme=light&cnt=15&pref_coin_id=1505&graph=yes" width="100%" height="940" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" border="0" style="border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe></div><div style="color: #FFFFFF; line-height: 14px; font-weight: 400; font-size: 11px; box-sizing:content-box; margin: 3px 6px 10px 0px; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;"><a href="https://coinlib.io" target="_blank" style="font-weight: 500; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;font-size:11px">Crypto Prices</a>&nbsp;by Coinlib</div></div>
```

But I get error:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /home.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 219] The reference to entity "theme" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?